# filtering ng repeat with nested object property is not working in Angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following `json`,

```
$scope.accountsList = [    {
      "id": 1,
      "number": "AFRC1234",
      "name": "ACFRYTE431", 
      "postalCode": "76565",
      "invoices": null,
      "courier": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "UPS"
      },
      "client": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "FREG",
        "name": "Feranget"
      }
    } ]
```

And I am filtering `ng-repeat` as ,

```
<tr ng-repeat="account in accountsList | filter:{ number: accountSearch.accountNumber,  name: accountSearch.accountName, client.name : accountSearch.clientName}">
```

And in my controller I have :

```
 $scope.accountSearch = {
                accountNumber :'',
                accountName : '',
                clientName : ''
        };
```

If I delete `client.name : accountSearch.clientName`, in ng repeat filtering criteria, the `accountsList`  is correctly getting filtered based on `accountNumber` and `accountName`. But when I include, `client.name : accountSearch.clientName` in ng repeat filter criteria, the following error is getting displayed in console and filtering of `accountsList`  is not happening.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 66 of the expression [accounts | filter:{ number: accountSearch.accountNumber,   client.name : accountSearch.clientName }] starting at [.name : accountSearch.clientName }].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=66&p3=accounts%20%7C%20filter%3A%7B%20number%3A%20accountSearch.accountNumber%2C%20%20%20client.name%20%3A%20accountSearch.clientName%20%7D&p4=.name%20%3A%20accountSearch.clientName%20%7D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
AST.prototype.throwError@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12881:1
AST.prototype.consume@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12893:1
AST.prototype.object@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12870:9
```

Can any one help how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your inline filter like that solves the problem.

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accountsList | filter:{ number: accountSearch.accountNumber,  name: accountSearch.accountName, client :{ name: accountSearch.clientName} }">
```

and here is the working plnkr check this .http://plnkr.co/edit/B3R758UjxldvZLDkxO8E?p=preview